# onClick(), onMouseOver() and onMouseOut() with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

So far I've got this working so that it has a "basic" image, click image, and change image to "active image, but I don't want it to revert back to the original image when you mouse out if the image has been clicked--I want it to stay on the click image until another image is clicked.

Here is my HTML

```
      <div id="booking_i">
       <img id="img" src="/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik.png">
       <img id="img2" src="/design/zebra/images/booking/2stolik.png">
      </div>
```

In js would be something like

```
onmouseover="image.src='/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik_aktiv.png'";
onmouseout="image.src='/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik.png'";
onClick="image.src='/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik_clicked.png'";
```

Comment: remove the onmouseout event..?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you remove the inline code and change to a separate .js file

Comment: but i need onmouseout because i've 3 different images for three different states

Comment: just've edited 1st post

Comment: declare a variable that will hold the selected imageID. onmouseout, escape the code if the variable is equal to the imageID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="booking_i">
    <img id="inage1" src="/design/zebra/images/booking/booking.png" />
    <img id="img" src="/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik.png" />
    <img id="img2" src="/design/zebra/images/booking/2stolik.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#image1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 103px;
    top: 300px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#img').onMouseOver.attr('src','/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik_active.png');
    $('#img').click(function () {
        this.attr('src', '/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik_clicked.png');
        $('#img2').attr('src','/design/zebra/images/booking/2stolik.png');
    });
    $('#img2').onMouseOver.attr('src','/design/zebra/images/booking/2stolik_active.png');
    $('#img2').click(function () {
        this.attr('src', '/design/zebra/images/booking/2stolik_clicked.png');
        $('#img').attr('src','/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik.png');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not using JQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked = false;
    $("#img").on({        
            mouseenter: function (event) {
                if(clicked)
                    return false;
                $(this).attr('src','new.jpg');  
            },
            mouseleave: function (event) {
                if(clicked)
                    return false;
                $(this).attr('src','new.jpg');
            },
            click: function (event) {
                clicked = true;
                $(this).attr('src','new.jpg');
            }
        },
        "body"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to the image once its been clicked and in the mouseover function test if this image has that class.

In case the class is not there continue, else preventDefault.

some thing like

```
$('.image').mouseover(function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
                // code to change source here
       }
});
```

in the click event use

```
$('.image').click(function(){
// to avoid repition
     if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
               $(this).addClass('clicked');
               // code to change the source
       }
});
```

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

are you using jquery?  then you can do this

```
$('#img').on('click', function () {
    //click event goes here
    $(this).attr("src", "/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik_aktiv.png");
});

$('#img').hover(
    function () {
        //hover event
        $(this).attr("src", "/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik.png");
    },
    function () {
       //hover out event 
       $(this).attr("src", "/design/zebra/images/booking/1stolik_clicked.png");
    });
```