# problems applying onClick(), onMouseOver() y onMouseOut() for changing an img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried everything commented in this post --> [onClick(), onMouseOver() and onMouseOut() with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579979/onclick-onmouseover-and-onmouseout-with-image) but no luck.

I want to change an image into another one (the `src` basically) when `onmouseover()` and `onclick()`. Also, when `onmouseout()` make the `img` come back to the original one.

My code:

```
<nav class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="banner">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li onclick="cambioSeccion('especialistas');" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img1');" onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img1');">
                        <a href="#" id="especialistasBoton"><i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img1" src="images/icons/Stethoscope.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;NUESTROS ESPECIALISTAS</a></li>
                    <li onclick="cambioSeccion('servicios');" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img2');" onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img2');">
                        <a href="#" id="serviciosBoton"><i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img2" src="images/icons/services.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;SERVICIOS</a></li>
                    <li onclick="cambioSeccion('aseguradoras');" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img3');" onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img3');">
                        <a href="#" id="aseguradorasBoton">
                            <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img3" src="images/icons/maletin.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;ASEGURADORAS Y MUTUALIDADES</a></li>
                    <li onclick="cambioSeccion('instalaciones');" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img4');" onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img4');">
                        <a href="#" id="instalacionesBoton">
                            <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img4" src="images/icons/House.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;INSTALACIONES</a></li>
                    <li onclick="cambioSeccion('dondeestamos');" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img5');" onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img5');">
                        <a href="#" id="dondeestamosBoton">
                            <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img5" src="images/icons/location.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;¿DONDE ESTAMOS?</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The JavaScript:

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

var activo = '#main-slider';


function cambioSeccion(seccion){

    if(seccion==='especialistas'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#especialistas').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#especialistas';
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
        changeImgToWhite('img1');
    }

    if(seccion==='servicios'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#servicios').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#servicios';
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
        changeImgToWhite('img2');
    }

    if(seccion==='aseguradoras'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#aseguradoras').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#aseguradoras';
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
        changeImgToWhite('img3');
    }

    if(seccion==='instalaciones'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#instalaciones').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#instalaciones';
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
        changeImgToWhite('img4');
    }

    if(seccion==='dondeestamos'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#dondeestamos').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#dondeestamos';
        $('#map-container').css("display","block");
        init_map();
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToWhite('img5');
    } else{
        $('#map-container').css("display","none");
    }
}

function changeImgToWhite(param){
    if(param === 'img1'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/Stethoscopewhite.png');
        $('#especialistasBoton').css('background-color', '#79BAB3');
        $('#especialistasBoton').css('color', '#FFF');
    }

    if(param === 'img2'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/serviceswhite.png');
        $('#serviciosBoton').css('background-color', '#79BAB3');
        $('#serviciosBoton').css('color', '#FFF');
    }

    if(param == 'img3'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/maletinwhite.png');
        $('#aseguradorasBoton').css('background-color', '#79BAB3');
        $('#aseguradorasBoton').css('color', '#FFF');
    }

    if(param == 'img4'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/Housewhite.png');
        $('#instalacionesBoton').css('background-color', '#79BAB3');
        $('#instalacionesBoton').css('color', '#FFF');
    }

    if(param == 'img5'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/locationwhite.png');
        $('#dondeestamosBoton').css('background-color', '#79BAB3');
        $('#dondeestamosBoton').css('color', '#FFF');
    }
}

function changeImgToOriginal(param){
    if(param === 'img1' && activo !== '#especialistas'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/Stethoscope.png');
        $('#especialistasBoton').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('#especialistasBoton').css('color', '#8E8E8E');
    }

    if(param === 'img2' && activo !=='#servicios'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/services.png');
        $('#serviciosBoton').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('#serviciosBoton').css('color', '#8E8E8E');
    }

    if(param === 'img3' && activo !=='#aseguradoras'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/maletin.png');
        $('#aseguradorasBoton').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('#aseguradorasBoton').css('color', '#8E8E8E');
    }

    if(param === 'img4' && activo !=='#instalaciones'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/House.png');
        $('#instalacionesBoton').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('#instalacionesBoton').css('color', '#8E8E8E');
    }

    if(param === 'img5' && activo !=='#dondeestamos'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/location.png');
        $('#dondeestamosBoton').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('#dondeestamosBoton').css('color', '#8E8E8E');
    }
}

/* Carrusel de aseguradoras */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    });
});
```

This doesn't do anything and I cannot figure out why.

**Edited:
I have edited the post to show how I solved my issue. I did that few days ago but I have improve it. Hope it will be helpful for those who may have the same problem in the future :).**

Comment: remove onclick="cambioSeccion('especialistas')" or use e.stopPropagation(); on that function supplying an event parameter..

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
<img id="img1" src="http://www.topazlabs.com/bweffects_static/img/grain_before.jpg" alt="logo">
<input type="hidden" id="bck-img" value="http://www.topazlabs.com/bweffects_static/img/grain_after.jpg" />

$('#img1').on('mouseover', function (event) {
    var thisSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var changeSrc = $('#bck-img').val();
    $('#bck-img').val(thisSrc);
    $(this).attr('src', changeSrc);
});

$('#img1').on('mouseout', function (event) {
    var thisSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var changeSrc = $('#bck-img').val();
    $('#bck-img').val(thisSrc);
    $(this).attr('src', changeSrc);
});
```

Check this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/rn6mg80z/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to thanks all of those that have helped me out.

I came up with one solution to my problem. It is the following one:

My HTML:

```
<nav class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="banner">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li onclick="cambioSeccion('especialistas')";>
                            <a href="#" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img1')"; onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img1')";>
                                <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img1" src="images/icons/Stethoscope.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;NUESTROS ESPECIALISTAS</a></li>
                        <li onclick="cambioSeccion('servicios');">
                            <a href="#" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img2')"; onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img2')";>
                                <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img2" src="images/icons/services.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;SERVICIOS</a></li>
                        <li onclick="cambioSeccion('aseguradoras');">
                            <a href="#" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img3')"; onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img3')";>
                                <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img3" src="images/icons/maletin.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;ASEGURADORAS Y MUTUALIDADES</a></li>
                        <li onclick="cambioSeccion('instalaciones');">
                            <a href="#" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img4')"; onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img4')";>
                                <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img4" src="images/icons/House.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;INSTALACIONES</a></li>
                        <li onclick="cambioSeccion('dondeestamos');">
                            <a href="#" onmouseover="changeImgToWhite('img5')"; onmouseout="changeImgToOriginal('img5')";>
                                <i class="fa">&nbsp;<img id="img5" src="images/icons/location.png" alt="logo"></i>&nbsp;¿DONDE ESTAMOS?</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var activo = '#main-slider';
var clicked1 = false;
var clicked2 = false;
var clicked3 = false;
var clicked4 = false;
var clicked5 = false;


function cambioSeccion(seccion){
    if(seccion=='especialistas'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#especialistas').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#especialistas';
        clicked1 = true;
        clicked2 = false;
        clicked3 = false;
        clicked4 = false;
        clicked5 = false;
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
    }else{
        if(seccion == 'especialistasFooter'){
            $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
            $('#especialistas').slideToggle( "slow" );
            activo = '#especialistas';
            clicked1 = false;
            clicked2 = false;
            clicked3 = false;
            clicked4 = false;
            clicked5 = false;
        }
    }

    if(seccion=='servicios'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#servicios').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#servicios';
        clicked1 = false;
        clicked2 = true;
        clicked3 = false;
        clicked4 = false;
        clicked5 = false;
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
    }else{
        if(seccion=='serviciosFooter'){
            $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
            $('#servicios').slideToggle( "slow" );
            activo = '#servicios';
            clicked1 = false;
            clicked2 = false;
            clicked3 = false;
            clicked4 = false;
            clicked5 = false;
        }
    }

    if(seccion=='aseguradoras'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#aseguradoras').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#aseguradoras';
        clicked1 = false;
        clicked2 = false;
        clicked3 = true;
        clicked4 = false;
        clicked5 = false;
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
    }else{
        if(seccion=='aseguradorasFooter'){
            $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
            $('#aseguradoras').slideToggle( "slow" );
            activo = '#aseguradoras';
            clicked1 = false;
            clicked2 = false;
            clicked3 = false;
            clicked4 = false;
            clicked5 = false;
        }   
    }

    if(seccion=='instalaciones'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#instalaciones').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#instalaciones';
        clicked1 = false;
        clicked2 = false;
        clicked3 = false;
        clicked4 = true;
        clicked5 = false;
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img5');
    }else{
        if(seccion=='instalacionesFooter'){
            $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
            $('#instalaciones').slideToggle( "slow" );
            activo = '#instalaciones';
            clicked1 = false;
            clicked2 = false;
            clicked3 = false;
            clicked4 = false;
            clicked5 = false;
        }
    }

    if(seccion=='dondeestamos'){
        $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('#dondeestamos').slideToggle( "slow" );
        activo = '#dondeestamos';
        clicked1 = false;
        clicked2 = false;
        clicked3 = false;
        clicked4 = false;
        clicked5 = true;
        changeImgToOriginal('img1');
        changeImgToOriginal('img2');
        changeImgToOriginal('img3');
        changeImgToOriginal('img4');
    }
    else{
        if(seccion=='dondeestamosFooter'){
            $(activo).slideToggle( "slow" );
            $('#dondeestamos').slideToggle( "slow" );
            activo = '#dondeestamos';
            clicked1 = false;
            clicked2 = false;
            clicked3 = false;
            clicked4 = false;
            clicked5 = false;
        }
    }

}

function changeImgToWhite(param){
    if(param == 'img1'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/Stethoscopewhite.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img2'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/serviceswhite.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img3'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/maletinwhite.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img4'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/Housewhite.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img5'){
        $('#' + param).attr('src','images/icons/locationwhite.png');
    }
}

function changeImgToOriginal(param){
    if(param == 'img1' && clicked1 == false){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/Stethoscope.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img2' && clicked2 == false){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/services.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img3' && clicked3 == false){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/maletin.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img4' && clicked4 == false){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/House.png');
    }

    if(param == 'img5' && clicked5 == false){
        $('#' + param).attr('src', 'images/icons/location.png');
    }
}
```

This code above make basically this--> http://jsfiddle.net/rn6mg80z/10/ but with other IMGs and structure. It is very easy to control the onmouseover and the onmouseout (you can even do it just with CSS) but the problem was in the onClick(). I wanted to kill the onmouseover and onmouseout functionality as soon as onClick() come into the game.

Hope this solution I came up could help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it shortly in this way :

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.mySwitch.src='http://pic-zoom.com/media/images/80c9b7b74b.png'" onmouseout="document.mySwitch.src='http://www.haberler.com/haber-resimleri/195/polat-alemdar-dan-itiraf-2418195_o.jpg'">

    <img src="off.gif" name="mySwitch" />

</a>
```

Comment: <a href="#" onmouseover="document.mySwitch.src='http://pic-zoom.com/media/images/80c9b7b74b.png'"
onmouseout="document.mySwitch.src='http://www.haberler.com/haber-resimleri/195/polat-alemdar-dan-itiraf-2418195_o.jpg'">
<img src="off.gif" name="mySwitch" /></a>

Comment: the first one is not my code.  I dont understan what happened.